# Alpha conversion in lambda

Tags: c#, programming-languages, lambda, lexical-scope

Why is C# does not support alpha-conversion?

```
int n = 3;
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int oddNumbers = numbers.Count(n => n % 2 == 1);
Console.Out.WriteLine("N value = " + n);
```

Yield:

> A local variable named 'n' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'n', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Is there any particulate reason that I am not aware of because it sound very silly?

Comment: Are all negative numbers even?

Comment: Ask microsoft that is where this the code was inspire from.

Comment: If you have a link, perhaps that particular documentation or example can be corrected.

Answer (score 11):

First off, your test for oddness is wrong.

The answer to your question is to deny the premise of your question. **This has nothing whatsoever to do with alpha conversion.**

Nor does it have anything to do with "lexical scoping", by which leppie seems to mean something different than my understanding of lexical scoping. **C# is a lexically scoped language.**

Now, I want to emphasize that *it is illegal to declare two locals in C# where one hides the other*. It is perfectly legal to hide in other scopes; a type parameter may hide an outer type parameter (though doing so is really, really dumb; do not do that.)  A field may hide a base class field (though you should mark the hiding field as 'new', to emphasize that fact.) A local may hide a method. And so on.

But a local may not hide another local, because (1) doing so makes bug farms, and (2) it violates the more general rule about usage of simple names.

**That rule about names is the interesting rule here.** You would get a similar error if you did this:

```
class C
{
    int n;
    void M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n); // n means this.n
        Func<double, double> f = n=>n; // n means the formal parameter
    }
}
```

The error you are getting is because you are violating the rule of C# that **a simple name must have a consistent meaning throughout the local scope in which it is first used.**

Programs where 'n' means one thing on one line and something completely different on the next are confusing and bug-prone, and therefore illegal.

If you want to do that then the two meanings of 'n' have to be in *non-overlapping* scopes:

```
class C
{
    int n;
    void M()
    {
        {
          Console.WriteLine(n); // n means this.n
        }
        Func<double, double> f = n=>n; // n means the formal parameter
    }
}
```

That would be legal because now the two usages of n are in non-overlapping scopes.

The problem has nothing whatsoever to do with alpha conversion. C# does alpha conversion just fine when it needs to.

**And it is *because* C# is lexically scoped that the compiler can determine that you are violating this rule.** This is not evidence that C# lacks lexical scoping; it is evidence that it *has* lexical scoping.

For more thoughts on this rule, see my article on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx

Comment: In a sense yes the compiler have to do some alpha-conversion to handle it properly. And I don't see the big deal whith some variable shadowing an other. It is surely not ideal but not that error-prone as you said. What is error prone is to have too many variables, temps and stuff like that. My method are never longer than 20LOC (in C#).

Comment: @mathk: If you have the discipline and ability to write only short methods then that's awesome; many problems go away. Not everyone does, and not everyone maintains code that they themselves wrote. I have spent many, many hours tracking down bugs in C programs that turned out to be caused by local variable shadowing. And yes, the fundamental problem was always long methods doing too much with too many variables.

Comment: @mathk: However, I still do not understand what you mean by "the compiler has to do alpha conversion to handle it properly". There are a very small number of situations in which the compiler runs an alpha-renaming algorithm on its internal data structures in order to do a correct analysis, and they pretty much all have to do with obscure scenarios involving generic type parameters.

Comment: An other thing about scoping. Yes dynamic scoping is harmful and no lexical scope have nothing to do with this issue. I mean that Scheme and Haskell and any other respectable PL that have lambda does not forbid variable shadowing.

Comment: @EricLipppert yes you are right there is no need of alpha conversion actually and yes in alpha conversion is only when you try to interpret a language. But when writing the question I did not though it thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

This is not really alpha conversion.

The problem is that C# does not have proper lexical scoping, which would imply that variables could be shadowed in inner scopes.

Comment: Yes you're right is not an alpha conversion. But the compiler could do a alpha conversion since it does not have a proper lexical scope

Comment: @mathk: I see it the other way around. If C# had proper lexical scoping, it would do an alpha conversion :)

Comment: C# most certainly does allow shadowing in inner scopes!

Comment: And C# is most certainly a properly lexically scoped language. You seem to be using "lexically scoped" to mean "allows declaration of locals that shadow other locals", but that is not at all what "lexically scoped" means. C# disallows that, not because it is dynamically scoped, but because **those programs are bug farms**. C# is a "pit of quality" language; the rules of the language are designed so that you have to work hard to write confusing bug-prone programs. Languages that allow locals to be confusingly named are "pit of despair" languages; they make it easy to write bugs.

Comment: @EricLippert: Allows shadowing? Eg `int i = 0; { int i = 0; }` is not valid. Unless you mean going outside method bodies.

Comment: @leppie: C# does not allow one local (or formal parameter or range variable) to hide another, because doing so makes bug farms. But it does allow locals to hide fields, allows type parameters to hide other type parameters, and so on.

Comment: @EricLippert: By **proper** lexical scoping, I imply by declaring a lambda (or delegate), it should introduce a new lexical scope (or contour). This would still comply to the 'local shadowing rules' (as you described above) as there are 2 distinct method bodies, and `int i = 0; { int i = 0; }` would still be invalid. Why C# allows this for classes and not closures, is inconsistent IMO.

Comment: It is better to think of a lambda as introducing a *local variable declaration space*. Remember, *scope* is *the region of program text in which an entity may be referred to by its unqualified name*. A *declaration space* is a logical container which contains declarations whose names do not conflict. **Local variable declaration spaces** have special rules about what declarations are legal when those spaces nest. **Those rules do not affect the scoping rules**.  Scoping is about *name resolution*. Declaration spaces are about *name declaration*. You are conflating the two.

Comment: And yes, it is *deliberately inconsistent*. The reason it is deliberately inconsistent is because *method bodies are fundamentally different than class bodies*, so why *shouldn't* the rules be different? It seems strange to expect two *different* things to have *the same* rules when doing so makes programs *buggier*. We value *preventing bugs* far higher than we value *foolish consistency*.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this occurs is in C# lamda functions are not declared in a scope. They are able to access variables inside the parent scope. For instance, the following code allows your lambda to access the variable n:

```
int outerN = 3; 
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 
int oddNumbers = numbers.Count(localN => localN % 2 == outerN); 
Console.Out.WriteLine("N value = " + outerN);
```

You should treat variables inside a lambda function as being in the same scope as the method they are declared in.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

> Lambdas can refer to outer variables that are in scope in the enclosing method or type in which the lambda is defined. Variables that are captured in this manner are stored for use in the lambda expression even if variables would otherwise go out of scope and be garbage collected. An outer variable must be definitely assigned before it can be consumed in a lambda expression.
>
> The following rules apply to variable scope in lambda expressions:
>
> - A variable that is captured will not be garbage-collected until the delegate that references it goes out of scope.
> - Variables introduced within a lambda expression are not visible in the outer method.
> - A lambda expression cannot directly capture a ref or out parameter from an enclosing method.
> - A return statement in a lambda expression does not cause the enclosing method to return.
> - A lambda expression cannot contain a goto statement, break statement, or continue statement whose target is outside the body or in the body of a contained anonymous function.

Comment: The question is why does C# have this 'limitation'.

Comment: @leppie this is not a limitation, it is by design so that lamda functions can access (value + reference types) and update (reference types) from outside a lamda. otherwise you would have to pass in an object containing all the parameters needed to a lambda in a similar way to the `object parameter` to ThreadStart. The syntax for lamdbas with paramter would then become `numbers.Count(localN => localN % 2 = (int)object[0], new object[] { outerN } )`, which is not only messy but also involves boxing/unboxing overhead in this example. Access to outer scope improves efficiency and readabilty

Comment: It **IS** a limitation. Countless other languages have no problem implementing proper lexical scoping. And yes, if you want to access a variable with the same name, you should not be shadowing it. There is no reason for explicit closures as in your `ThreadStart` example.

Comment: @DrA even if it’s by design – and it *is*, if I remember some post by Eric correctly – it’s still a limitation, just an intentional one. Either way, your description of the problem is wrong as explained by leppie.

Comment: @leppie possibly because C# is strongly typed and variables cannot be re-interpreted. F# is the closest .NET language to what you want - they have somehow managed to achieve dynamic yet strong typing

Comment: @KonradRudolph - feel free to post a more accurate answer, I will gladly +1 it! :)

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson: Nothing to do with typing. I am pretty sure F# and Haskell and SML all have proper lexical scoping. (Correct me if wrong)

Comment: What is the issue of shadowing a outer variable?

Comment: @mathk: Nothing IMO, but C# does not allow it.

Comment: @leppie IMO too ;) @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson you said "You should treat variables inside a lambda function as being in the same scope as the method they are declared in." You are going to do a big mistake if you think that. For example: `delegate int F();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
            List<F> b = new List<F>();
            int oddNumbers = numbers.Count(n => { b.Add(() => n); return true; });
            b.All(n => { Console.Out.WriteLine("N value = " + n()); return true; });
            
        }`

Comment: Though I appreciate the reference to the spec, this answer actually does not explain the problem.

Comment: Guys, if you have a better answer, please feel free to add it.

Comment: Update: My mistake - page refresh and we have a answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper term is "shadowing", as in "C# does not allow one local variable to shadow another."

There are no technical reasons for the restriction. Shadowing does not cause problems for type checking or code generation.

I believe the motivation for this restriction is purely ergonomic. I expect that when the folks at Sun were designing Java (note: Java had this restriction too, and MS probably said eh sounds reasonable and put it in C# too) they figured that shadowing would trip up the programmers that they wanted to steal from the C and C++ communities. And they probably figured that the Lispers and Smalltalkers and MLers and whatnot would either live with it or refuse to use such a low-level pedestrian language anyway.

And I kind of agree with their assessment of the ergonomic issues. When you're modifying a large block of code it's possible to inadvertently capture variable references if you add a new local binding. In other words, textual program edits are not properly lexically scoped.